# Inject values of a Map with Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have a [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice) managed service that injects a couple of other services. The other services are used depending on a key value that is passed to my service method. So I want to make a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) that maps the service to use to the corresponding key:

```
@Inject
private IServiceA serviceA;

@Inject
private IServiceB serviceB;

private Map<String, IService> mapping;

private Map<String, IService> getMapping() {
    if (mapping == null) {
        mapping = new HashMap<String, IService>();
        mapping.put("keyA", serviceA);
        mapping.put("keyB", serviceB);
    }
}

@Override
public void myServiceMethod(String key) {
    IService serviceToUse = getMapping().get(key);
    // ... use some methods of the identified service
}
```

This solution works but seem awkward, because I have to have this lazy initialization of the mapping. I tried to use a `static` block, but the instance members are not yet initialized by Guice at this point.

I would prefer to inject the mapping values directly with Guice, but I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: I may be off-topic, you may consider using a different pattern: you could *@Provide* your IService classes, and use the @Named annotation to map each of them with a string

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use a [`MapBinder`](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.html), e.g.

```
protected void configure() {
    MapBinder<String, IService> mapBinder 
        = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, IService.class);
    mapBinder.addBinding("keyA").to(IServiceA.class);
    mapBinder.addBinding("keyB").to(IserviceB.class);
}
```

Then you inject the entire map, e.g.

```
public class IServiceController {
   @Inject
   private Map<String, IService> mapping;
}
```